# Getting a URL from a REST Service and then using it in webdriver through soapUI

Tags: rest, selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy, soapui

I'm using soapUI at work to test web services. In a lot of my tests i have transferred property values from one response to another request and vice versa, but now I'm stuck.

In one of my tests, I have a rest service that gives me a URL in response, and for my testing i want to open that URL in a browser to make sure that the url is valid.

I have tried HTTP Request but that doesn't work, therefore I wanna see if I can do that through selenium webdriver. Below is my script that I want to run in the next step after getting the URL.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I want to use the URL that I get from the rest service inside driver.get, but I don't know how to implement that. Also when I right click on my groovy script window in soapUI, I get a option of Get Data, can that work as well? If yes, then how can I implement that?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you edit the question and add screen shot of rest service for which you need url?

Comment: Hi Rao, I don't need the URL. I get a URL from rest service. The rest service is about making a one time payment which in response gives me a  URL that has a success message to it. What I want to do is, open that URL through selenium webdriver using groovy. Also, the URL has a unique session id whenever I run the rest service.

Comment: Do you have any request / payload / body  / parameters / headers needs to be send to that url? Does it really needs to be opened in a browser only? what happened when you have used http request?

Comment: I don't see any response when using HTTP Request. It might be an SSL certificate issue, but i'm not sure. And yes I have to open the URL, that's the part of the test unfortunately.

Comment: parse the url from your initial HTTP response and pass it to driver.get()

Comment: Thanks Corey, It worked. Can you please reply to the question as an answer so that I can mark it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

parse the url from your initial HTTP response and pass it to driver.get()